# Количество нажатий на элемент textView

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно посчитать количество нажатий на элемент textView и сделать так, чтобы свойство text этого textView отображало количество нажатий на элемент в виде числа.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    textView.setOnClickListener {
        textView.text.toString().toInt().plus(1).toString()
    }
}
```

При таком решении выдает NullPointerException. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не помешало бы лог добавить

Comment: UI где задается и поле textView кто инициализирует?